# sub domain dns delegation from AWS Route 53 to somewhere else

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

Let's say I have domain called example.com registered through AWS Route 53.
And I want to create subdomain called sub.example.com
But I want to use custom dns server running on AWS EC2
I created following Records
1. sub.example.com  NS ns.sub.example.com
2. ns.sub.example.com A X.X.X.X
3. DNS is up and running on X.X.X.X

When I do dig and nslookup I am getting error.
What should it be the SOA section?
and how can I make it to work?

Comment: Do you have `ns.sub.example.com A X.X.X.X` record created both on `X.X.X.X` and in Route53?

Comment: Can you post the DNS records you have from example.com that delegate NS to your custom EC2 name server? Also can you post the error you are getting from dig or nslookup?